# Get a Dropdown of Post Titles using this api

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a plugin that has an api for adding for fields.  I am able to add a category drop like this

```
$cats = get_terms('category');
$blog_cats = array("all" => "All");
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$blog_cats[$cat->name] = $cat->name;
}

<div class="description">
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category') ?>">
Category<br/>
<?php echo aq_field_select('category', $block_id, $blog_cats, $category); ?>
</label>
</div>
```

That works fine for a dropdown of categories.  Now I need to add a dropdown of post titles.  This is what I have tried without success:

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'post_type' => 'playlists');
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
$post_types[$post->ID] = the_title();
endforeach;

<div class="description">
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('playlist') ?>">
Playlist<br/>
<?php echo aq_field_select('playlist', $block_id, $post_types, $playlist); ?>
</label>
</div>
```

I can get a dropdown of posts when coding the form normally, my problem is making it work with this little api.

Comment: The plugin is called aqua page builder: https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Page-Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

```
global $post;
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'post_type' => 'playlists');
 $posts = get_posts($args);
 $post_types = array("" => "");
 foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
 $post_types[$post->ID] = get_the_title($post->ID);
endforeach;
```